# Determine the "edge" points given the equation of the line

Tags: algorithm, graph, coordinates

For a given line of an equation `y = mx + c` where `m` is the gradient and `c` is the y-intercept. How would I determine the "edge-points" on a graph?

To clarify what I mean by "edge-points", I've added an example below.

[image: Example graph]

The edge-points are circled in red. To determine the edge-points here it would simply be `(0, c) & (maximum x-value, m * maximum x-value + c)`. However, the problem arises when I consider lines with a different `m` value. For example:

[image]

I can't apply the same logic here, instead the edge-points would be `((maximum y-value - c) * m, maximum y-value) & (-c * m, 0)`, which was derived from the equation `y = mx + c`. So my question is how would I determine these 2 edge-points given any `m` or `c`? Is there a certain pattern I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve 4 simple linear equations (not equation system!):

```
y = m * 0 + c = c
y = m * maxX + c
0 = m * x + c
maxY = m * x + c
```

and get points of intersections with axes and with max lines. Then filter out points with negative coordinates and too large ones, because you want only the 1st quadrant

The first one equation is already solved `y=c`
The second gives point of intersection with right vertical line
The third gives point of intersection with OX axis
The fourth gives point of intersection with top horizontal line

Example:

```
maxX = 5
maxY = 5
line  y = 2 *x - 1
x0, y0 = 0, -1
x1, y1 = 5, 9
x2, y2 = 1/2, 0
x3, y3 = 2, 5
```

First pair contains negative coordinate `y=-1`
Second pair contains `y=9 > maxY`
Third and fourth ones fulfill your constraints.

So this line gives segment `(1/2, 0)-(2, 5)`  (like near vertical segment at your second picture)

This algo might be considered as simple kind of [line clippping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)#Algorithms) by rectangle

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you please add an example?

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, thank you. Final question, how would you know which paris of x,y to use?  In the example you use x2,y2 and x3,y3 how would you know these are the paris you should use?

Comment: Because another pairs contain negative or too large coordinates. Added one more description.

Answer (score 0):

For the line to be in the given rectangle there is a constraint given by the x values and a constraint given by the y values.

The x constraint trivially leads to an interval in which the x values must be.

The y constraint also gives you such an interval for the x values but only after some easy calculation.

Now determine the intersection of the two intervals (which may also be empty).